# What is the uncertainty in time if I am doing a video analysis of a falling object using my phone camera at 60 FPS. Is it just ±1/60s?

Tags: error-analysis

As a physics experiment where I was trying to find the terminal velocity of an object, I decided to record the drop and analyse it on Loggerpro frame by frame, but did not use a stopwatch. I created a position vs. time graph, so I could use the gradient as the velocity. I recorded at 4k 60 FPS, but I am unsure of the uncertainty in my time.

Answer (score 3):

The best source for questions on estimating and reporting uncertainty is the NIST guide: https://emtoolbox.nist.gov/Publications/NISTTechnicalNote1297s.pdf

In section 4.6 it describes how to treat a measurement like this. Basically, at 60 FPS if you can identify the single frame where an event happened then that gives the time to within $\frac{1}{60}\text{ s}$.

The actual time of the event could be anytime in that window, with equal probability. So you would model it as a uniform distribution so, per section 4.6, the estimated standard uncertainty would be $$u=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\frac{1}{60}\text{ s}$$ The factor in front accounts for the shape of the distribution.

Comment: This is the most conservative estimation of uncertainty. It's not likely the hardware is that bad.

Comment: The uncertainty is the uncertainty of estimating the time, not specifically the uncertainty of the hardware. I agree that it is unlikely that the hardware is that bad, but I do not think this is a conservative estimate of the uncertainty in the time estimation. On the contrary, I would be concerned that the estimate is overly optimistic. It may be difficult from the images to determine which frame an event occurred due to pixel resolution, motion blurring, bad camera angle, etc. In which case the time estimation will be even worse, regardless of the fact that the hardware is better.

Comment: https://thesmartphonephotographer.com/mobile-camera-shutter-speed/